# Adding element with a specific style using appendchild method

Tags: javascript, css, dom, appendchild, createelement

This is my code :

```
(a=document).getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a.createElement('div').style.cssText="someCssStyle");
```

it doesn't work !
but when i write only this :

```
(a=document).getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a.createElement('div'));
```

It works, so why can't I add the div element with a specific style?
What's wrong with my work?
I want to add a div element with a specific style just from the URL implantation on chrome using :

```
javascript://all of my code goes here
```

So it must be short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > a.createElement('div').style.cssText="someCssStyle"

This will return "someCssStyle" which will be given as argument to `(a=document).getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(` function. So the div is never added. Can you see the problem here ?

You have to create the div, style it and then add it to the body. Like this

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.cssText = "someCssStyle";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that here:

```
...appendChild(a.createElement('div').style.cssText="someCssStyle")
```

you're passing a *string* (`"someCssStyle"`) into `appendChild`, rather than the element reference. The result of an assignment in JavaScript is the right-hand value.

I don't recommend it, but you can use [the comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14) to do this:

```
(a=document).getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(d=a.createElement('div'),d.style.cssText="someCssStyle",d);
```

Note that your code, and the above, both fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Or more reasonably, a function:

```
(function(){var a=document,d=document.createElement('div');d.style.cssText="someCssStyle";a.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(d)})();
```

...which amongst other things *doesn't* fall prey to *THoIG*.

Comment: same for the style code right ?  
`d.style.cssText="height:100px,width:50px"` but not  
`d.style.cssText="height:100px;width:50px"`

Comment: @user1283226: No, styles are separated with `;`, not `,`. The comma operator is a JavaScript thing.

Comment: ok so the code will not work because i have too many styles to apply  
i think i will add style before appending the div  
like your third code but directly with no function  
thanks a lot sir

Comment: @user1283226: You need the function. Otherwise, you're adding/overwriting global variables to the page, which is a Very Bad Idea(tm). :-) (Particularly if they're `a` and `d`.) See (look in the JavaScript console): http://jsbin.com/enicag/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/enicag/1/edit)].